# Write Query in Parent Child like tree format

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I am working on a MVC C# project and I have some complication for my SQL query. I have three tables

1. Customer
2. Level
3. LevelDetails

Both tables have a relationship

Level mapped to Level Details and Level Details mapped to both customer and Level

I want to show that data in tree format eg:

Parent: Customer Name  CustomerId  Customer Type

```
     Test          T1          TestCustomer
```

Child    Levelid  Leveldesc  city  state

```
      L1       L1desc     C1    S1

      L2       L2desc     C2    S2
```

The logic is when I click the Parent it shows the Child Levels.

I am tried this query

```
select LD.Level_Rid, LD.Customer_Rid, LD.Level_Detail_Rid, L.Level_Id, L.Level_Description, L.Country, L.State, L.City, L.Area, CU.Customer_Name, CU.Customer_Type
FROM [dbo].[Level] L
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Level_Detail] LD ON R.Level_Rid = RD.Level_Rid 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customer] CU ON LD.Customer_Rid = CU.Customer_Rid
```

Is it possible to SQL query?

[image]

Comment: I am using Sqlserver.I need Parent - child Tree format in sql Query

Comment: Your probably want a recursive CTE.

Comment: @Dotnet I have added an answer but I think the best thing to do is handling this kind of business in code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written this query with a cte:

```
WITH cte_cu as 
 ( select Customer_Rid from  [dbo].[Customer] as cU )
--select * from  cte_cu where CustomerRid = CustomerRid
select Customer_Rid, 1 orderKeeper,Customer_Name as CustomerName ,[State] as [State],City,Customer_id from  [dbo].[Customer]  where Customer_Rid = Customer_Rid
union
select Customer_Rid,2,'LevelId' as Customer_Name ,'LevelDescription' ,'','' from  [dbo].[Customer]
union
select Customer_Rid,3,Level_Id as Customer_Name ,Level_Description,'','' 
FROM [dbo].[Level_Detail] LD 
inner join dbo.[Level] as L on LD.Level_Rid = L.Level_Rid 
where LD.Customer_Rid = Customer_Rid
```

Result:

[image]

I uploaded Create Table and Insert Mock data on git hub:

https://github.com/mghanatabady/SQL-Samples/blob/master/Write%20Query%20in%20Parent%20Child%20like%20tree%20format.SQL

Comment: @Dotnet If I have got a mistake, let me know, I can improve or change my answer